# Why does the lambda instruction return different results?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, split, apply

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['AB,CD'],['AB,FJS'],['DG']],
                   index = [1,2,3],columns=['A'])
```

Why do the following two codes return different results

```
for i in df["A"]:
    for n in i.split(","):
        print(n)
```

which returns

```
AB
CD
AB
FJS
DG
```

but the other code

```
def fx(x):
    for i in x["A"]:
        for n in i.split("，"):
            print(n)
df.apply(lambda x: fx(x), axis = 1)
```

returns

```
A
B
,
C
D
A
B
,
F
J
S
D
G
```

So, why does lambda return different results? And how can I change the lambda code to return the  same results as the previous one?
Thanks in previous

Comment: the string in the `.split` method is different

Comment: @XxJames07- -but results are still different after that correction.

Comment: because `x` is not the dataframe itself.

Comment: instead of `for i in x["A"]:` try `for i in x:`, x is already a series

Comment: Instead of `lambda x: fx(x)`, you can just use `fx`.

Answer (score 0):

The results are different because lambda function is applied to each row separately. So, for example, in the first row `x` is `AB,CD` and when you write `for i in x["A"]`, you iterate over each separate symbol.

```py
def fx(x):
    for i in x["A"].split(","):
        print(i)
df.apply(lambda x: fx(x), axis = 1)
```